# un-normalised string comparison

Tags: java, arrays, char, hashtable

My problem is that I have a list of jobs in an array called N such as "Accountant" , "Quantity surveyor". I want to take input such as "Chief Accountant" and change into Accountant.

The method that I came up is:

1. lower case both - input and the array
2. remove the white spacing
3. compare the each character in the input against each character from the job stored in N.
4. q , where q = sameChar/length of the current job

   5. Store the Standardised job name and it's corresponding q value in the hashtable

My problem is that I am having trouble comparing characters between the two strings. Could any one point me what it is I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

EDIT - Tried using the method proposed by tucuxi but I am getting an error when trying to execute it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.HashMap.add
    at Normaliser.normalise(Normaliser.java:41)
    at Normaliser.main(Normaliser.java:49)
Java Result: 1



import java.lang.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Normaliser {

    public static int distance(String a, String b) {
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
        // i == 0
        int [] costs = new int [b.length() + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < costs.length; j++)
            costs[j] = j;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++) {
            // j == 0; nw = lev(i - 1, j)
            costs[0] = i;
            int nw = i - 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= b.length(); j++) {
                int cj = Math.min(1 + Math.min(costs[j], costs[j - 1]), a.charAt(i - 1) == b.charAt(j - 1) ? nw : nw + 1);
                nw = costs[j];
                costs[j] = cj;
            }
        }
        return costs[b.length()];
    }

    public static HashMap<String, Integer> normalise(String jobTitle, String[] normalTitles) {

        HashMap<String, Integer> normalized = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String n : normalTitles) {
            normalized.add(n, n.length() - distance(normalTitles, n));
        }
        return normalized;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] normalTitles = new String[]{"Lawyer", "Engineer", "Accountant"};
        HashMap<String, Integer> qs = normalise("Process Engineer", normalTitles);
        for (String n : normalTitles) {
            System.out.println("job: " + n + " q: " + qs.get(n));
        }    
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure what your code is supposed to achieve. If there are any repeats, ```jobs.put(N[i], q)``` will overwrite old values with new. Also, since the normalizer method has no output and touches no class attributes, all calculations will be lost at the end of the call. Can you edit your post to show expected input and output for, say, jt = "Accountant"?

Comment: What I am trying to do is is store the value of q with its corresponding job. I will then iterate through the hashtable and output the job with the highest q value.

Comment: Then you would probably be better off using "edit distance" instead of "same letter in same position" metrics. Example: "Coloring Specialist" vs "Colouring Specialist" -- edit distance is 1, but only 4 letters share position.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for from the description. Would you want strings like "Front end engineer" to be output as "Software Engineer"? Assuming, no, the following roughly works:

```
public static String normalise(String jobTitle) {
    if (jobTitle == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] normalTitles = {"Architect", "Software engineer", "Quantity surveyor", "Accountant"};
    for (String normal : normalTitles) {
        if (jobTitle.toLowerCase().contains(normal.toLowerCase())) {
            return normal;
        }
    }
    return jobTitle;
}
```

At the very least,

```
System.out.println(normalise("Chief accountant"));
```

prints

```
Accountant
```

Comment: Yes this exactly what I am trying to achieve but I am also trying to work out q , which is how much do they match.

Comment: and I want to calculate it for each one and then display the one with the highest q value.

Answer (score 0):

From comments, I understand you want to input a job title and find the closest "normalized" job titles. I suggest using a different distance metric than "characters in same positions", such as [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```
String a = "Coloring Specialist";
String b = "Colouring Specialist";
charsInSamePosition(a, b); // = 4, even though they are really close
a.length() - levenshteinDistance(a, b); // = 19, as expected
```

Using the implementation of `levenshteinDistance` from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Java, the final code could be:

```
    public static HashMap<String, Integer> normalize(String jobTitle,
            String[] normalTitles) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> normalized = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String n : normalTitles) {
                normalized.put(n, jobTitle.length() - distance(jobTitle, n));
        }
        return normalized;
    }
```

A sample call:

```
String[] normalTitles = new String[]{"Lawyer", "Engineer", "Accountant"};
HashMap<String, Integer> qs = normalize("Process Engineer", normalTitles);
for (String n : normalTitles) {
    System.out.println("job: " + n + " q: " + qs.get(n));
}
```

Sample output:

```
job: Lawyer q: 2
job: Engineer q: 8
job: Accountant q: 3
```

Comment: Had a go and tried using your method but I get an error.

Comment: Fixed that for you. But you really should have specified what error you were finding...